# Issues with scss compiling with Grunt, not detecting certain styles for certain classes. Expression Engine

Tags: html, css, sass, gruntjs, expressionengine

Having strange issues compiling SCSS with Grunt when moving from development branch to a theme / CMS branch in Expression Engine.

To fully explain what's going on, there are currently two versions of a website being developed. One is built primarily in HTML / SCSS / Javascript and the SCSS is being compiled into CSS with Grunt. The other is a CMS system build in Expression Engine of the same site, so I am transitioning the first version's code over to other version, broken up in a way so that it can be used within a theme.

The problem here is the CSS that compiles correctly in the development (version 1) version are not compiling correctly in the CMS (version 2) version, but only for certain classes, and not every class is affected.

The HTML and CSS that are affected are as follows:

```css
.hero {
 padding: 80px 0;
 background: $color_blue_light url('../images/90650310_temp.jpg') no-repeat top center;
 background-size: cover;
 
  h1 {
   font-size: 6em;
   font-weight: 900;
   line-height: 1em;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
  }
}

.mobile-logo{
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row mobile-logo">
    <div class="col fixed-width">
     <a href="/"><img src="/assets/images/AHC_Logo.svg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
      
      <div class="row hero">
  
  <div class="container hero-h1">
   <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam id augue non felis</h1>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

In version 1, it displays the page correctly, pasted here: [image: working mobile]

In version 2, you see this: [image: non-working-mobile]

So in conclusion, version 2 isn't detecting the h1 styles, nor does it detect the class "mobile-logo" where the styles "display:none;" are found. BUT it is detecting other classes and are displaying those correctly, it's only these two classes that are getting messed with. I can't find any reason why this is happening other than something going on with Grunt...but there are no error messages. All I see when I compile and save is the following, it looks as though it doesn't just compile, it's getting sent to a sass-cache folder that I didn't create. Screenshot attached: [image: Coda 2 sass issue]

Looking online and on stack overflow about caching it looks like this is normal for sass and is beneficial to compiling. I don't really see how this would cause the upset, unless there's a rule in there collecting certain styles. Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the process was found in the Grunt file.

```js
watch: {
  compass: {
   files: ['**/*.{scss,sass}'],
   tasks: ['compass:dev']
  }
```

This compiles the SCSS within the dev environment. Changing ['compass:dev'] to ['compass:prod'] and creating that file path like so will fix this issue and compile in the correct place

```js
 prod: {
    options: {              
        sassDir: ['build/assets/sass'],
        cssDir: ['public_html/assets/css'],
        environment: 'production',
        outputStyle: 'compact'
    }
 },
 

grunt.registerTask('default', ['compass:prod', 'concat', 'watch']);
```